# C++/CLI library targetting .netcore as a dependency for VS 2017 C++ application

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, visual-c++, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to invoke .Netcore functions from a c++ application.

For that, I am having a C++/CLI library which inturn takes .Netcore library as dependency and then calls .Netcore functions from that library. I take this C++/CLI library as a dependency for a c++ application and then run the c++ application.

C++/CLI library -> TestCPPCLI

.Netcore library -> TestNetcoreDll

VS 2017 C++ application -> Testcpp

When I try to run the c++ application, I am getting the error `Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'TestNetcoreDll, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.`

During the compilation of `TestCPPCLI`, I am getting this Linker warning `1>LINK : warning LNK4199: /DELAYLOAD:TestNetcoreDll.dll ignored; no imports found from CVMQClient.dll`

In VS2017 c++ application, can we take dependency of an C++/CLI library which is targeting .Netcore?

**How I have included .Netcore library in C++/CLI application in vcxproj ?**

```
<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
    <CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
    <CharacterSet>MultiByte</CharacterSet>
    <CLRSupport>NetCore</CLRSupport>
    <PlatformToolset>v142</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="TestNetcoreDll">
   <HintPath>..\..\..\Build\x64\Release\TestNetcoreDll.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>      
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemDefinitionGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
     <Midl>
      <PreprocessorDefinitions>_DEBUG;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)</PreprocessorDefinitions>
      <MkTypLibCompatible>true</MkTypLibCompatible>
      <SuppressStartupBanner>true</SuppressStartupBanner>
      <TargetEnvironment>Win32</TargetEnvironment>
      <TypeLibraryName>$(OutDir)$(ProjectName).tlb</TypeLibraryName>
    </Midl>

    <ClCompile>
      <ForcedUsingFiles>TestNetcoreDll.dll</ForcedUsingFiles>
    </ClCompile>
    
    <Link>
      <DelayLoadDLLs>TestNetcoreDll.dll;%(DelayLoadDLLs)</DelayLoadDLLs>
    </Link>
  </ItemDefinitionGroup>
```

In `vcxproj`, I have included library and header file locations as well in `AdditionalLibraryDirectories` and `AdditionalIncludeDirectories`

Comment: Is the intent to call .Net code from a fully native application? Or from native code that is part of a managed .Net application? In the former case you need to run the CLR in some way, since the managed code needs to be jitted before it can be run.

Comment: @JonasH  : I need to call from a fully native application developed using VS 2017

Comment: Not something I have ever done, but you might want to take a look at [Hosting .NET Core Components in Unmanaged C/C++ Process in Windows and Linux](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1276328/Hosting-NET-Core-Components-in-Unmanaged-C-Cpluspl). I would also consider just running the .net code in a separate process and use some IPC/RPC to communicate.

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot link the dll, you need add it as a reference.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Reference Include="TestNetcoreDll">
    <HintPath>TestNetcoreDll.dll</HintPath>
  </Reference>
</ItemGroup>

<!--ClCompile>
  <ForcedUsingFiles>TestNetcoreDll.dll</ForcedUsingFiles>
</ClCompile>

<Link>
  <DelayLoadDLLs>TestNetcoreDll.dll;%(DelayLoadDLLs)</DelayLoadDLLs>
</Link-->
```

Comment: I have this as well as part of my vcxproj. But still facing the same error. I have updated the vcxproj at the top.

Comment: Make sure `TestNetcoreDll.dll` and your application are placed in the same folder.

Comment: Yes, It is in the same directory. Whether since it is because of .NetCore library it is not loaded.

Comment: The error message means it cannot find the assebly file, try to use `AppDomain::AssemblyResolve` event to load `TestNetcoreDll.dll` with its full path.